# Cannot string together multiple “-c” options using vim from the terminal

Tags: command-line

I execute a set of handy commands I need to do often on a standard type of file using the `-c` (or equivalently, the `+`) option from command line using vim. However, after an update to the remote system's OS, commands beyond the first one are interpreted as different file names and results in the first command being executed and multiple buffers being opened rather than multiple commands being executed on one file.

The command I use is `vim -c ':11' -c ':norm wllv,dZZ' myfile` (go to line 11, move over a few characters, select the current position, and replace using a leader command, and then save and exit).
With the change on the remote system, this now results in two buffers being opened, one is `wllv,dZZ` and the other is `myfile`

Vim also throws this error:

```
Error detected while processing command line:
E471: Argument required: :norm
```

Furthermore, if I try `vim -c ":11" -c ":21" myfile`, both commands work and no extra buffer is opened, which indicates the error is perhaps somewhere with `:norm`, but I'm not sure why as this was working just fine very recently.

Current version of vim is 7.4, in case that helps.

Any help restoring the old behavior or understanding where the issue is coming from would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Added output from `xxd` for a bash script containing only the vim command above:

```
0000000: 2321 202f 6269 6e2f 6261 7368 0a76 696d  #! /bin/bash.vim
0000010: 202d 6320 273a 3131 2720 2d63 2027 3a6e   -c ':11' -c ':n
0000020: 6f72 6d20 776c 6c76 2c64 5a5a 2720 6d79  orm wllv,dZZ' my
0000030: 6669 6c65 0a                             file.
```

Pseudocode version of the wrapper script:

```
if [ $LOGNAME == "root" ]; then 
    <some logic here for when it's run by root> 
else 
    /usr/bin/vim $* 
fi
```

Comment: This isn't sounding like a Vim issue but it would help if you provide more details. What remote OS? How are you accessing Vim on the remote system? SSH? What SSH (or whatever) client are you using? What's the local OS? Etc.

Comment: @BLayer Using ssh in WSL (so locally, I have Ubuntu from April 2020) to access the remote system, which is running some unknown flavor of linux

Comment: Can you try with a more up-to-date vim or no? My first thought was that perhaps the vim9 stuff had broken command-parsing but that shouldn't apply to such an old vim

Comment: @D.BenKnoble unfortunately i can't install new software on the remote machine. i suppose i could try to compile vim9 in my local directory, if you think that could really help? it's not clear to me why it wouldn't just have the same issue though...

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! SSH will often mess with whitespace in your command line. Maybe try something like: `ssh remotehost 'vim -c ":11" -c ":norm wllv,dZZ" myfile'`, in other words, put the *whole* remote `vim` command inside single quotes and then use extra double quotes for the arguments to `-c`? Not sure that's the exact invocation you need, but start there and experiment until you find the one that works...

Comment: does it matter if you use `vim -c ":11" -c ":norm wllv,dZZ" myfile`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt double quotes don't change the result. Double quotes are actually more dangerous as they could result in bash expanding something in the command, although that wouldn't happen here...

Comment: @filbranden i'm SSHed into the remote server, not sending the command over SSH, not sure if that would make a difference in your suggestion? I don't think I'm encountering an issue with the whitespace, and it's not obvious how messing with the white space would result in my problem?

Comment: @anwho I know. It's for testing if that works. Try escaping the quotes. Or even better, put the commands into a vimrc file and source that `:so myvimrc`

Comment: Just spitballin' here but I'd try this (all on the remote system): put your command in a file, say "test.sh" and run it with `bash test.sh`. If you get the same result dump it's bytes with `xxd test.sh`, share it via pastebin or add it to your question here....that'll allow checking for any funky/unexpected characters (perhaps due to some over-the-wire encoding issue).

Comment: @BLayer added ```xxd``` output, same issue persisted.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt not sure what you mean by "try escaping the quotes"! However, your idea of putting the commands into a script worked, when I sourced the script from within the file. Unfortunately, as soon as I tried ```vim -c ":so myscript" myfile``` I ran into the same issue as before.

Comment: Does `file $(which vim)` tell you `vim` is a binary (something like "ELF 64-bit LSB ...") or a script (something like `#!/bin/bash script`)? If it's a wrapper script, maybe it's a wrapper that is breaking arguments with spaces in them? Do you think that's a possibility?

Comment: @filbranden vim is indeed a wrapper script. Added a little pseudocode version of the script, keeping what appear to be the most important parts to the question above.
I don't see anything here that obviously would break the passed on arguments?

Comment: Oh yeah the `$*` is the problem! I'll post an answer.

Comment: Thanks @filbranden and everyone else who helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `vim` in your system is a wrapper script that includes a bug that will essentially discard any whitespace in the arguments and re-parse the arguments again.

The problem is the use of `$*`, which simply expands the arguments and lets the shell parse them again, without keeping track of which word was which original argument.

You can fix that wrapper script by changing it to:

```bash
if [ $LOGNAME == "root" ]; then 
    # <some logic here for when it's run by root> 
else 
    /usr/bin/vim "$@"
fi
```

The important part here being the use of `"$@"` (including the double quotes!) to ensure that the arguments are kept intact.

(BTW, you might want to also change that line to `exec /usr/bin/vim "$@"`, which ensures the wrapper script is replaced by the vim program when that line is executed. That way if the process is killed with a signal, the signal will go to the Vim binary and not to the shell running the wrapper script.)

Comment: *sigh* classic sysadmin mistake. Why this logic is needed is beyond me, but there it is. I prefer `sudoedit` for root editing though.

Comment: If you prefer to avoid the script, you could adjust your path so /usr/bin comes earlier, or set EDITOR and VISUAL to /usr/bin/vim and invoked vim through those

Comment: Thank you so much @filbranden ! Since I can't edit the wrapper function, I just aliased vim to run ```/usr/bin/vim``` and I submitted a bug report to the sys admins. :)